# Setting foreign key constraint name using NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys

I am using NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate as the ORM of my application. I frequently use export schema to generate the database, and then compare with an existing database. Due to the fact that NHibernate generates the name of the constraints I get a lot of noise when comparing. All tables are marked as changed each time.

I'd like to stabilize the constraint names using some convention such as FK_TableName_ColumnName.

I cannot get this to work however.

I've got this so far:

```
public class ForeignConstraintNamingConvention : IReferenceConvention, IHasManyConvention, IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.ForeignKey(GetForeignConstraintName(instance.Name, instance.Columns.First().Name));
    }

    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.OtherSide != null)
        {
            instance.OtherSide.ForeignKey(GetForeignConstraintName(instance.TableName, instance.OtherSide.Columns.First().Name));
        }
    }

    private static string GetForeignConstraintName(string tableName, string columnName)
    {
        return string.Format("FK_{0}_{1}", tableName, columnName);
    }

    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Relationship != null)
        {
            instance.Relationship.ForeignKey(string.Format("FK_{0}_{1}", instance.TableName, instance.Relationship.Columns.First().Name));
        }

        if (instance.OtherSide != null && instance.OtherSide.Relationship != null)
        {
            instance.OtherSide.Relationship.ForeignKey(GetForeignConstraintName(instance.OtherSide.TableName, instance.OtherSide.Relationship.Columns.First().Name));
        }
    }
}
```

But instance.OtherSide is often null, I assume this is because the reference is unidirectional most of the time, and I'm not interested in the other side of the relation, except that I need to use stable key names. Given that the "other side" is null, there is no way for me to set the foreign key constraint name for that key.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve fully stable constraint names, ideally based on the actual columns / tables involved?